# How to set disabled text color for JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, foreground, uimanager

How to set the disabled text color for every `JLabel` in my program. It is not in the docs . Is there any way to set the disabled foreground color for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it. Foreground can be set using UI Defaults.

```
// Use the key, Label.disabledForeground
UIManager.put("Label.disabledForeground",Color.RED);

JLabel l=new JLabel("Label Disabled");
l.setEnabled(false);
// You get a red foreground
```

For `NimbusLookAndFeel`

```
UIManager.put("Label[Disabled].textForeground",Color.RED);
```

Comment: *"can be set using UI Defaults. .. For `NimbusLookAndFeel`"*  That is the main problem with using UI defaults - they are not consistent across PLAFs.  :(

Comment: +1 Andrew. since I've always been a `Metal` man, I never knew this.

Comment: please for why reason could be JLabel editable or not, JLabel isn't designated for this purposes

Comment: @mKorbel JLabel is a sub class of JComponent before all! It is ours, no one, even the Swing team can decide what we should do with a component, we'll just play with it! ;)

Comment: @mKorbel I agree with your comment, but I didn't see where he mentioned `editable`. He just asked about the `enabled` state.

Comment: sure with drums to hares, I'm againts hot head with !!! and to reinvent the wheels, from curiosity to allergy